# Content on a usb flash drive available for a limited time

Tags: encryption, usb

I need to distribute some content on a USB flash drive. This content should be available for a limited time only.

I am looking for some approach to achieve above.

So far I do not have information about what kind of content will be on there or what OS the consumers will use. I am looking for ideas, general information, some known approaches for similar tasks.

Answer (score 2):

DRM-based solution may be the only solution to such need.

With such solution, when the client opens the document / software / whatever is stored on the USB key, the application must contact your server requesting for a key to decipher the document.

All you have to do then is to decide at which moment you stop distributing the key for this document.

Properly implemented, DRM also limits copy possibilities since even if someone copies the content of the USB flash drive, it will remain ciphered and the key from your server will still be needed in order to open it.

The main drawback for such feature is that it requires a compatible software (for instance Adobe Acrobat for .pdf files) and that a network connectivity is required.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the USB drive is run on a customer's equipment, there is no way its content can be made available for a limited time only.  This because the customer can control the time of the machine where the USB drive is accessed.  The only way you could do this is to have an USB firmware with an embedded clock which wipes out the content of the flash drive, but this looks too complicated a solution to me.

You might find other physical solutions e.g. distributing your content on FlexPlay DVDs, which become unreadable 48h after opening the sealed package.  However, still this doesn't allow to have a specific moment in time where the content is made non accessible.

Finally, you have to consider that you're handling digital data.  The main concern here is the possibility that the customer could make a copy of the binary data, which would still be accessible after the original content has expired.